# How to use TensorFlow to predict large csv files by chunks and glue results together

Tags: tensorflow

Now that I've trained a predicting model with TensorFlow, and there's a large test.csv file that's too big to fit into memory, can it be possible to feed it by a smaller chunk at a time and then concat them again within one session?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tf.estimator.Estimator` for your model and calling the `predict` method using the `numpy_input_fn` will give you all the pieces to build what you want.